Calculating Inductance for RFID PCB Antennas (13.56 MHz) – Discrepancies in Results
I'm trying to calculate the inductance for various RFID PCB antennas (13.56 MHz). I used the tool from ST's Antenna Design tool (second image), but the results don't match the expected values shown in the first image. Could someone help me identify where I might be going wrong? Additionally, I would appreciate guidance on how to calculate the inductance for the PCB antenna shown in the third image.
Thanks in advance!





Could someone help me identify where I might be going wrong?

Your board is 5.4 cm x 3.9 cm but, in the 2nd image you are saying the coil is 54 mm x 49 mm. Do I really need to spell this out?

In addition, if you fill the centre of your coil with circuitry it's bound to reduce the inductance or even cause the electronics to fail.
